# Delay packets using Netem on Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terminal, virtualbox

I'm trying to delay packets using Ubuntu on a virtual machine, but when I type in the terminal:
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
I get:
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted.

I'm working as an intern and I got assigned to a clock synchronization project on a network and I need to be able to create asymmetry in time for packets being sent and received and my prof told me to use netem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around and realized I needed to use the sudo command so I added sudo before the "tc qdisc..."
I'm fairly new to linux so I don't know many stuff. My bad!